# Get a random value from list

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

Using the SoapUI tool, I have created a loop that takes values from the GET respone and passes them to the DELETE method. The value of GET will change because each loop, some values will be removed.
I would like to retrieve random values, which are located in the method GET respone.

**Form:**

```
${Take#Response#$['data'][*]['id']}
```

In this way we retrieve the entire list of values. I would like to get a random value from the available values.

**Raw:**

```
"id" : "[13, 19, 10, 21, 14, 24, 17, 12, 11, 25]",
```

I tried to replace `[*]` as follows `[${=(int)(Math.random()*25)}]`
Unfortunately, this solution will not be effective because not all IDs are available, some have already been deleted.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
import java.util.Random 
Random random = new Random()
def list = [13, 19, 10, 21, 14, 24, 17, 12, 11, 25]
def randomValue = random.nextInt(list.size())
def theValue = list[randomValue]
```