# Random variable value with many random elements

Tags: xpath, soapui

I want to use a random value from the GET method, in the POST method.

List car = Audi, Porsche, Ford, VW, Honda, Citroen

```
$['carTypes'][0]['carType']['enum']
Result: [Audi]

$['carTypes'][${=(int)(Math.random()*6)}]['carType']['enum']
Result: [Porsche] (random 1 car from the list of 5 available)
```

**I would like to get a list of random cars but not limited to just one car - random list of cars but in the range of 0 to 6, not only 1 value.**

```
Result: [Audi,Porsche]
Result: [Ford, VW, Honda]
Result: [Citroen]
```

I have tried like this.

```
$['carTypes'][${=(int)(Math.random()*6)},${=(int)(Math.random()*6)}]['carType']['enum']
Result: [[Citroen, Honda]]
```

Probably 2 flat brackets **[[** prevent me from using this data in the POST method, how to get rid of unnecessary brackets?

Groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
Random random = new Random()
def list = ["Porsche","Ford","VW"]
def randomValue = random.nextInt(list.size())
def list2 = ["Porsche","Ford","VW"]
def randomValue2 = random.nextInt(list2.size())
def theValue = list2[randomValue2] +","+  list[randomValue]
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: can you give an example of what you're getting with `GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the above in your post step, you could create a Groovy script step in between the GET and POST requests.

In the Groovy script, you can then 'build' the string exactly how you want, including the removal of the brackets.  The last line in the script should be a return statement that returns the string you built.

In the POST request, you can then 'pull' in the value from the groovy script step using the $ functionality.  E.g. ${Groovy Script Name#result}

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how should the script look like, solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903670/get-a-random-value-from-list applies to Int, String does not work

Comment: I entered the code in groovy, but it has the disadvantage that the values in the selected string can repeat, do you know how to avoid it?

Comment: I'd use a loop constrained the random number of items.  Then add the cars from the source array to the output array, but check whether it exists first.